# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in Tensorflow 1.13.1 from java on windows 10

Tags: java, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to use tensorflow from java program on windows 10. I have followed all the instruction from here https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_java carefully. I am getting following exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\hokl\AppData\Local\Temp\tensorflow_native_libraries-1551615368173-0\tensorflow_jni.dll: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
at org.tensorflow.NativeLibrary.load(NativeLibrary.java:101)
at org.tensorflow.TensorFlow.init(TensorFlow.java:66)
at org.tensorflow.TensorFlow.(TensorFlow.java:70)
at org.tensorflow.Graph.(Graph.java:361)
```

Comment: Have you solve it?